# Horizontal progress bar width in actionbar

Tags: android, width, android-actionbar, progress

I'm displaying an horizontal progress bar in my action bar.
My problem is the progress bar width is not the action bar width, but smaller (but centered). Is that a normal behavior? How can I give it the screen width?

I'm using this in onCreate

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

and this in my methods

```
public void setShowIndeterminateProgress(boolean val) {
    setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
    setProgressBarVisibility(val);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried testing in the emulator and at least 2 different devices?

Comment: can you put a screen of that?

Answer (score 2):

There is an attribute `android:progressBarPadding` in the action bar style. Set it to `0dip`.

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:progressBarPadding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all items from your menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    //inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_main, null);

    //actionBar.setCustomView(view);
    return true;

}
```

Then after that create an xml layout with progress bar. In it width="match_parent".
Uncomment actionBar.setCustomView and this method to inflate your actionBar with your own custom view.

Try that and give me a sing does it work for you.